# How do I protect my signup/ registration apis

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm using identity server to protect my apis, to access the backend resources, a client must request a token based on user credentials and pass them to the next apis to consume them. My question is, how do I protect my registration apis when there is no user yet and hence no credentials to generate a user token? here's my thinking process:

**Option 1: apply rate limit on my signup apis to limit brute forcing and api abuse:**

Problem: the users of my app live in worker camps where they share the same wifi and the rate of calls from one ip being high is a reality.

**Option 2: use captcha**

Problem: my user base is not familiar with captchas (for certain reasons) and business conversion would be hurt by using captchas.

**Option 3: Use OAuth2 with client id and secret to protect those particular apis:**

Concern: I might be wrong but I think such authentication is best used between two systems, as someone can sniff the network and get those client ids and secrets and comprise the apis.

What do you think is a good solution to this?

Comment: Sniffing: Should not happen if the communication protocol is secured (https/tls). Captcha: Valid concern. Per IP rate limit: Should be no problem as long as you only count the invalid attempts (either amount or better %).

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to implement both recaptcha as well as API rate limiting. Recaptcha will prevent the bot attack and API rate limiting will prevent the Denial of Service attack.
Latest version of google recaptcha do not need the user to enter text in the textbox.